# Reading from IBM MQ Uniform cluster in a balanced fashion

Tags: ibm-mq

We've set up an IBM MQ uniform cluster(with a set of Queue managers (QM1, QM2 and QM3). on 3 different servers.We have a question on workload balancing ...while the MQPUTs are distributed across queue managers cluster queues, we have a problem with reads(MQGET)...Reads are happening on one queue manager while others wait.

The application instance that issues MQGET is a single threaded and cannot be scaled , is there a way that we could use the application to get messages from Queues on cluster in a balanced fashion ?

Comment: The whole purpose of uniform clusters is to balance multiple readers across multiple queue mangers. What you are asking with a single reader is not something MQ handles. You could code your app to connect to multiple queue mangers or PUT disable the clustered queue on all but one queue manger, but then there really is no reason to use uniform clusters. You can use normal clustering to allow failing over the queue manager that receives messages. For your use case you might want to look into RDQM instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @JoshMc states, in uniform clustering multiple instances of an application are balanced across multiple queue managers. But since you only have one instance of your 'getting' application, it can't be distributed across several queue managers.

However, assuming there are no sequencing/affinity requirements for your messages, you could connect *multiple instances* of your getting application to the uniform cluster which would then get rebalanced to each queue manager.

Comment: Hi @sjain, this is not true.   MQPUTs will be work load balanced from the queue manger the application is connected to all available instances of a queue.  There is nothing in MQ or clustering that will distribute MQGETs across multiple queue mangers.   The app would need to have logic to do this as I stated in my original comment.

Comment: Answer has been clarified after comments made by @JoshMc

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, I can't upvote yet as I don't have the necessary points on Stack overflow. Can we use a Load balancer on top of IP port pairs ? and does it make any better?

Comment: Not from a GETing standpoint.